# In javascript, How to check if the last element of an array is a number or not. Note that the last element can have either number or string depends

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
console.log("case 1")
var event = "Year 2021";
console.log(typeof(parseInt(event.split(" ").pop())) === "number");
console.log("case 2")
var event = "Year mukesh";
console.log(typeof(parseInt(event.split(" ").pop())) === "number");
console.log("case 3")
var event = "Year mukesh";
console.log(typeof(event.split(" ").pop()) === "number");
console.log("case 4")
var event = "Year 2021";
console.log(typeof(event.split(" ").pop()) === "number");
```

> case 1 when we have a proper number in last place with using parseInt gives true and that is legit!

> case 2 when we have a string in last place and still using
> parseInt...should give false but because of parseInt it gives us valid
> number type
>
> case 3 when we have a string in last place without using parseInt...
> gives false that too is legit!
>
> case 4 when we have a number in last place without using parseInt..
> gives false that is too is legit! well because "2021" is a string
> because 2021 is indeed enclosed within " ".
>
> Now how do I check if the last element of the array is a string or an
> integer because from the user I could receive any combination either a
> "Hello darkness" or "Hello 221".

[Check on jsfiddle for more clarification](https://jsfiddle.net/5wth0vmj/)

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212).
See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212). `typeof(event.split(" ").pop()) === "number"` is the same thing as `false`. `String.prototype.split` never returns an array with a number. Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)? Do you know how to [convert a string to a number](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#function_syntax) or `map` arrays with `.map(Number)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to determine whether a value is NaN or not:

```js
console.log("case 1")
var event = "Year 2021";
console.log('Is a number?', !isNaN(event.split(" ").pop()));
```